# How to port Android 4 button styles to a lower platform?

Tags: android, button, styles

I'm currently developing an app running on android api 4 (1.6) and above.
However, it looks very good on android 4 (with it's new button styles) but it looks stupid on all platforms below, including 1.6 (The button style there is awkward).

How can I make the buttons view on all platforms equally?
Can I copy the `android 4 button style` to my project to solve this issue?
If yes, where may I find this style.

This is what it should look like *everywhere*:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. All you need to do is to create a custom background and copy some files from your SDK directory.

Put this as an xml drawable in your drawables folder. I called it btn_start_activity.xml. But you can give it any name you want.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

Now Eclipse will complain that it can't find the files. You need to copy them from sdk.dir/platforms/android-15/data/res/drawable-xxx to your project. Take care that you copy the ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi versions.

Now create an xml file in your res/color folder. I assigned the name: primary_text_btn_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark"/>
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_holo_dark"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_holo_dark"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_holo_dark"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_holo_dark"/>
    <item android:color="@color/bright_foreground_holo_dark"/> <!-- not selected -->
</selector>
```

Now add the missing color values to your colors.xml in res/values.

```
<color name="bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark">#ff4c4c4c</color>
<color name="bright_foreground_holo_dark">#fff3f3f3</color>
```

Then apply the new style to you buttons

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_start_activity"
android:textColor="@color/primary_text_btn_start"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find all drawables and styles here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res

If you want to take just the buttons it's enough to pick the drawables corresponding to each density and the style. These are found in the same location under "values" folder.